# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument --disable-gpu

Tags: google-chrome, powershell

I am trying to create a powershell process where I can print my local webpage via automation.

```
start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="C:\Temp\createPdf180304023549.pdf" http://localhost/
```

The problem with it though is it keeps saying

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument --disable-gpu

However, the commands I'm using are copied from https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `ArgumentList` parameter to your command as follows:

```
start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList @"--headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="C:\Temp\createPdf180304023549.pdf" http://localhost/"
```

Note that the arguments have been wrapped in double quotes and prepended with an at sign (@) to escape the double quotes in the print-to-pdf argument.

Without this parameter, PowerShell will interpret the arguments intended for Chrome as arguments for the Start-Process cmdlet.

---

[Start-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6)

Comment: i use the same but i am getting error. but my answer will work in all cases. there is a double quota issue in above answer

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me

```
start-process chrome.exe -ArgumentList "--headless --print-to-pdf=C:\Users\{User}\Desktop\AllPdf\pdf4.pdf https://www.google.com"
```

Comment: That's essentially the same answer already given. If there are reasons for the difference, listing WHY you went with these particular arguments will make this seem less like you're just copying what others have done without adding anything meaningful to the answers.